# I imported bootstrap to my react project and it distorted my already made style, I posted the code below

Tags: css, reactjs

```
.nav{
position: absolute;
top:40px
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

The justify content portion of the code isn't working since I imported bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Justify-content` property is capitalized.
This is the reason why it's not working in your code, not Bootstrap.
Change the property to:

```
.nav{
  position: absolute;
  top:40px
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Also, there is no need for `flex-direction:row;`, as that is the default property for flexbox.

Comment: I see you've edited your original post. I assume that didn't work out for you?